# How to sort this string correctly

Tags: python, string, sorting

I have a string:

```
"John 20 Paul 10"
```

I need to get out of this:

```
"Paul 10 John 20"
```

But! if the numbers are the same you need to sort alphabetically:
I have
    "Paul 20 John 20"
I need

```
"John 20 Paul 20"
```

(because the letter J in the alphabet is the firster than P). such names and numbers can occur 1 time per line (John 20) or 3 or any another number (John 15 Paul 10 Michael 20)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: In what sense? I want to sort the string given to me in this way, but I don't know how. You mean my actions or the whole code task?

Comment: First split the string. Then think about sorting.

Comment: you didnt actually ask anything, you just showed us what was asked of you. without an actual question i will just tell you how i would approach the problem. i would turn the string into a dict where the keys are the numbers and the values are lists of the corresponding names

Comment: break down your problem in smaller problems. you need to __split__ the string into different parts and __sort__ them right? and then __join__ them back in one string? why don't you google these keywords? protip: use `split()`, `sort()`, and `join()`.

Comment: are you alluding to the use of dict? okay, I'll try. This question, because I have no idea what to do here, so I decided to ask in General, so as not to put the wrong question. If you didn't understand, I'm sorry. P. s sorry for my english, I am from italy

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be helpful if you post the code you have so far. In your post you are only showing a problem, but not where to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way that [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) works, using it here will be a bit harder than necessary (because the data is delimited by the same delimiter used as separator between data points). This can be solved by using a basic [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html), [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/sorting.html) with a basic [`key` function](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) (twice) to turn the created list of tuples (created by `re.findall`) back to a string.

```
import re

string = 'John 15 Paul 10 Michael 20'
data = re.findall(r'([A-z]+) (\d+)', string)
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda t: (int(t[1]), t[0]))
print(' '.join(' '.join(t) for t in sorted_data))
```

Outputs

```
Paul 10 John 15 Michael 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Using str split

```
s = "John 20 Paul 10"

# Split into words
words = s.split()

# form word pairs (i.e. words[i:i+2] will be a name and a number
word_pairs = [words[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(words), 2)]

# sort words based upon word pairs 
# tuple (int(x[1]), x[0])) allowing sorting by number and name 
sorted_pairs = sorted(word_pairs, key= lambda x: (int(x[1]), x[0]))

# Aggregate back into a string
result = ' '.join([' '.join(x) for x in sorted_pairs])
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
Paul 10 John 20
```